# Custom page admin 404

Tags: module, magento-1, 404-page

When my structure in this `app/code/community/Mage` it works, but when this pattern in `app/code/community/Mymodule`... page returns 404

I do not know what to do so that I can access the page normally

etc/modules/Mymodule_Payment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Payment>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Mymodule_Payment>
    </modules>
</config>
```

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <mymodule translate="label" module="paygate">
                    <label>Mymodule</label>
                    <sort_order>670</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>                        
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Active</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>01</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </active>
                    </fields>
                </mymodule>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Payment>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mymodule_Payment>
    </modules> 
    <global>
        <resources>
              <mymodule_payment_setup>
                    <setup>
                          <module>Mymodule_Payment</module>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                          <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
              </mymodule_payment_setup>
              <payment_write>
                <connection>
                  <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </payment_write>
            <payment_read>
               <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
            </payment_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mymodule_Payment_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mymodule_Payment_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
        </models>        
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mymodule_Payment_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mymodule_Payment>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mymodule_Payment.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mymodule_Payment>
            </modules>
        </translate>        
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <mymodule>
                        <Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml</Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml>
                    </mymodule>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mymodule_Payment>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mymodule_Payment.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mymodule_Payment>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <mymodule>
                <active>0</active>
            </mymodule>
         </payment>
    </default>  
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mymodule_menu translate="title" module="mymodule">
        <title>PagSeguro</title>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <children>
                <mymodule_conciliation translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>Conciliation</title>
                    <action>mymodule/adminhtml_conciliation</action>
                    <sort_order>2000</sort_order>
                </mymodule_conciliation>
                <mymodule_abandoned translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>Abandoned</title>
                    <action>mymodule/adminhtml_abandoned</action>
                    <sort_order>2100</sort_order>
                </mymodule_abandoned>
                <mymodule_config translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>Configurações</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/payment/</action>
                    <sort_order>2200</sort_order>
                </mymodule_config>
            </children>
        </mymodule_menu>
    </menu> 
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <mymodule_adminform>
                                <title>PagSeguro</title>
                            </mymodule_adminform>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

controller/Adminhtml/ConciliationController.php

```
class Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml_ConciliationController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {   
        $this->loadLayout();        
        $this->_setActiveMenu('mymodule_menu')->renderLayout();             
    }       
}
```

controller/Adminhtml/AbandonedController.php

```
class Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml_AbandonedController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {   
        $this->loadLayout();        
        $this->_setActiveMenu('mymodule_menu')->renderLayout();             
    }       
}
```

Comment: put config.xml code here?

Comment: removed the menu config.xml and put in adminhtml.xml @AmitBera

Comment: the module complete this in question @AmitBera

Comment: this example also of 404 - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <mymodule>
                    <Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml</Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml>
                </mymodule>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

replace it

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <payment before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Payment</payment>         
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: is it resolved.??

Answer (score 4):

**Issue1:** controller file location is wrong

```
controller/ConciliationController.php
```

it should be controller **s**

```
 ../Mymodule/Payment/controllers/Adminhtml/ConciliationController.php
```

As you define class **Mymodule_Payment_Adminhtml_ConciliationController**

**Issue2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <menu>
        <mymodule_menu translate="title" module="mymodule">
        <title>PagSeguro</title>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <children>
                <mymodule_conciliation translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>Conciliation</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/conciliation</action>
                    <sort_order>2000</sort_order>
                </mymodule_conciliation>
                <mymodule_abandoned translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>Abandoned</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/abandoned/index</action>
                    <sort_order>2100</sort_order>
                </mymodule_abandoned>
                <mymodule_config translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>Configurações</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/payment/</action>
                    <sort_order>2200</sort_order>
                </mymodule_config>
            </children>
        </mymodule_menu>
    </menu> 
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <conciliation translate="title" module="mymodule">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                    </conciliation>
                </children>

            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

[Creating a Simple Admin Module - Routing Problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/creating-a-simple-admin-module-routing-problem)

http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-routers-a-look-under-the-hood

Comment: structure controller/Adminhtml/ConciliationController.php was already certain, put the router and not resolved, which I find strange that the /Mage works and outside /Mage 404 @AmitBera

Comment: is it full config.xml?

Comment: have you create Mymodule_Payment.xml at app/etc/modules?

Comment: I have, the module works properly when it is not 404 app/code/community/Mage/Payment ... but does not work in app/code/community/Mymodule/Payment @AmitBera

Comment: ok .i will check